# Python setup.py: a lot of additional folders in project

Tags: python, packaging, distutils

I had some issues with importing my custom package into project.
I've created very simple `setup.py` file.
It looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup

import custom_package

setup(
    name='custom_package',
    version=custom_package.__version__,
    packages=['custom_package'],
)
```

Then I'm installing it into my system:

```
python setup.py install
```

`custom_package` becomes available, but there are a lot of additional folders in my project after this command:

```
build/
dist/
custom_package.egg-info/
```

Is it expected or I should avoid them somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is to be expected, because you don't limit the files that should go into the package by using the `setup` argument `package_dir`. Without that `setup` will take everything from the directory that it is in, which includes the directories it makes for storing the structure that has to go into the installable archive (`build`) , as well as the destination directory for the final `.tar.gz`: `dist`).

This is one of the reasons why many package layouts have the habit of having a src subdirectory to store all the sources. You can add a list all the `.py` files that have to go in as a list, or use some helper function to generate that list (which is easier if you already have everything under one directory that is "clean".

Comment: Well, after replacing `packages=['custom_package'],` with `package_dir={"": 'custom_package'}` it looks like it works the same. All of mentioned folders are created too.

Comment: and where are the `dist` and `build` directories. They should **not** be under `custom_package`. Also make sure you include and update your version number on each run of `python setup.py sdist` otherwise you might be installing an old `.whl`. `pip` has a tendency to reuse wheels if the version number of the latest package doesn't get upated.

Comment: @smart I reread your post this morning and realiised you are probably not speaking of getting those directories when you install the package, (in the install locaton) but about getting them in your original source directory because of running `python setup.py install`. Can you confirm that? I can update my question with two methods on how to do that.